# cocoa menubar error [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: macos, cocoa, menubar

I want to add some array elements to the menubar cocoa desktop application

here is my code with error

```
NSMenu *menu =[[NSMenu alloc]initWithTitle:@"menu"];
NSMenuItem *itemTest = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" action:@selector(menuActionTest:) keyEquivalent:@"t"];    
NSMenuItem *itemQuit = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit App" action:@selector(menuActionQuit:) keyEquivalent:@"q"];



// add to menu
[menu addItem:itemTest];
[menu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]];


// handle the array, and here is the problem
NSArray* someList = [self getArray];
if ([someList count]>0) {
    for(NSString *title in someList) {
        NSLog(@"begin of add %@",title);
        // here is the problem code
        [menu addItem: [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:title action:@selector(menuActionHelloWorld:) keyEquivalent:@""]];
        NSLog(@"end of add %@",title);
    }
    [someList release];
    [menu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]];
}

// add other to menu
[menu addItem:itemQuit];


//Define status bar-------------
NSStatusBar *bar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
NSStatusItem *statusItem = [[bar statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength]retain];

NSImage *menuImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"status_off.png"];
[menuImage setTemplate:YES];
[statusItem setImage:menuImage];

[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
[statusItem setMenu:menu];

//Release----------------------
[itemTest release];
[itemQuit release];
[menu release];
```

when I use

```
[menu addItem: [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:title action:@selector(menuActionHelloWorld:) keyEquivalent:@""]];
```

the application can build well, but when I click the status icon in the menubar, I got the error message

```
2012-02-24 16:20:38.393 MyApp[1546:503] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x202ecc3
2012-02-24 16:20:38.394 MyApp[1546:503] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x202ecc3
2012-02-24 16:20:38.398 MyApp[1546:503] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff85ebbfc6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff86c1cd5e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff85f482ae -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 190
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff85ea8e73 ___forwarding___ + 371
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff85ea8c88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff85e1f616 CFStringGetLength + 118
6   HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cb95d07 _Z12CheckForDashP8MenuDatathPKhPK10__CFString + 100
7   HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cb95c84 _Z26CleanupAfter1ItemInsertionP8MenuDatatPKhPK10__CFStringj + 41
8   HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8cb95823 _Z31_InsertMenuItemTextWithCFStringP8MenuDataPK10__CFStringtjj + 204
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff84ff8cfd -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonMenuInsertItem:atCarbonIndex:] + 499
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8513c1a2 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _privatePopulateCarbonMenu] + 298
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff851c17a5 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _populatePrivatelyIfNecessary] + 70
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff851c174b -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _checkoutMenuRefWithToken:creating:populating:] + 298
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff852edd46 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _maximumSizeForScreen:] + 64
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8545f72b -[NSMenu size] + 35
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff855517df +[NSStatusBarButtonCell popupStatusBarMenu:inRect:ofView:withEvent:] + 422
16  AppKit                              0x00007fff85551b85 -[NSStatusBarButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 147
17  AppKit                              0x00007fff850d2bde -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 786
18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8509d6e0 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6306
19  AppKit                              0x00007fff85552598 -[NSStatusBarWindow sendEvent:] + 66
20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8503616d -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5593
21  AppKit                              0x00007fff84fcc1f2 -[NSApplication run] + 555
22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8524ab88 NSApplicationMain + 867
23  RandomApp                           0x00000001067390e2 main + 34
24  RandomApp                           0x00000001067390b4 start + 52
```

I am a newbie to Cocoa, I try to solve this problem by myself.

I find

```
[__NSCFNumber length]
```

so I think the problem occurs from this line

```
 NSStatusItem *statusItem = [[bar statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength]retain];
```

This line is copied from apple example :) It Makes the status item length dynamic, adjusting to the width of its contents. [NSStatusBar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

I think I set a variable length NSString as title, so the application can not decide how much its length value should be.

To prove that, I write my code as

```
[menu addItem: [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"HelloWorld" action:@selector(menuActionHelloWorld:) keyEquivalent:@""]];
```

it works well.

But I really need to get the title dynamically.

So, how can I fix my code?

Thanks!

**edit 1:**

thanks

I add

```
NSString *newTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",title];
```

to my code, it works.

So I think the problem becomes my method getArray

here is some codes in my getArray method

```
NSMutableArray *List = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for ( some conditions) {

// get something from a JSON result
NSString *title = [object valueForKeyPath:@"id"];

[List addObject:title];

}

return List;
```

To my point of view, the List is an array of lots of NSString elements, but I think I am wrong. what should I do to improve my code? To much better?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're accidentally passing an `NSNumber` in as your title. (I'm guessing this because code works fine when adding HelloWorlds, and `length` is a commonly-used method on `NSString`.)

I'd need to see your implementation of `getArray` to know exactly what went wrong, but I bet that knowing you've got an `NSNumber` in there by accident will be enough for you to solve it. (By the way, it's Cocoa-stylish to name your accessors simply `array`, not `getArray`.)